# Regarding SQL query 'join' function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created the following table but have troubles getting the desired output using the join function. I would like to know that if we have to select car name, price and driver name for cars made in any random year e.g.,vintage = 1995. Any help will be appreciated

```
create table car
(car_ID  NUMBER ,
car_Name CHAR ,
car_Vintage NUMBER,
car_Price NUMBER,
PRIMARY KEY (car_ID));

create TABLE driver
(driver_ID NUMBER,
driver_Name  CHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (driver_ID));

create table cardriver
(car_ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
driver_ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (car_ID,driver_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (car_ID) REFERENCES car(car_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (driver_ID) REFERENCES driver(driver_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us what you tried.

Comment: Have you read any documentation describing how JOIN works?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    c.car_Name, 
    c.car_Price, 
    d.driver_Name 
FROM 
    cardriver as cd 
INNER JOIN 
     car as c on c.car_ID = cd.car_ID 
INNER JOIN 
     driver as d on d.driver_ID = cd.driver_ID 
WHERE 
     c.car_Vintage = @Year
```

This assumes every car has a driver. Otherwise select from car and left join to cardriver.

Comment: Thankyou. I tried your above mentioned solution and received ORA-00933. Error at line 2; SQL command not ended properly for the FROM cardriver as cd